# Sending data from non function to the other in the same view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to allow my users to create new projects in the platform I am building through Django.

The idea is, as soon as the user created the project through the form, and click submit, I want the page to jump to the details page of the project they just created.

My idea was to get the model.id and pass it to see the project_details page.

However, Django has an error message that says, the UUID is not valid. Does that mean when I retrieve the UUID, the model is not created in the database yet? Or I need to do something else, so the function and query the database again before it send to the project_details page?

Please see my code snippet here.

```
def daycare_profile_details(request, pk):
    daycare_object = DayCareProfile.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'daycare_object': daycare_object, 'pk': pk}
    print(type(pk))
    return render(request, 'daycare_profile/single_daycare_profile_detail.html', context)


def create_daycare_profile(request):
    form = DayCareProfileForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DayCareProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            new_daycare = form.instance
            new_id = str(new_daycare.pk)
            context = {'pk': new_id}
            return redirect('daycare_profile_details', context)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'daycare_profile/create_daycare_profile.html', context)
```

Comment: The model should be created when you hit that `render` ..This `UUID is not valid` sounds
like a form error, maybe that UUID is already in the database (very likely while
testing) - where specifically, what line, is this error message hitting on?
**Side Note:** idk if that render syntax will work, usually it's like: `render('daycare_profile_details', pk=pk)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  \n I think the  create_daycare_profile function definitely created the model already because I can find it in the admin panel. Oh, I have tested the type of the pk, which is the same as you click from all the objects list. It is very confusing for me ... 